# Getting Json data into a list view

Tags: android, json, listview

I have been searching for a way to get the json data from a URl (for example: http://search.twitter.com/trends.json) and display it in a listview. Couldnt get a perfect example to get it done. Can anyone plz help me out by getting the solution and providing a good example of how to do it...

Comment: Post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android comes with Json-lib so parsing JSON is easy.  You just need to use the HTTPclient classes to retrieve the data from the URL, and you can use the JSONObject class to parse the JSON. And write a ListAdapter to pull data from the JSONObject.

Comment: Can u please provide me a working example of how to do it coz i m still a newbie... PLzzzzz

Answer (score 1):

found this tutorial : http://damonsk.com/2010/01/jsonarray-httpclient-android/